# Geocode not finding some locations

Tags: carto, geocoding

Most of my data is geocoding in cartodb except a handful.  I've verified the location exists using google maps but it's still not coding it.  For example, here's a location it's unable to code:

3641 S TACOMA AVE
TULSA, OK  74107
US

I've attempted to code using city & postal code with no success.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to add separating commas between Street, City, State, Zipcode and Country. This allows the system to recognize your addresses better.

Check the result: [image]

PS: Notice that you can add the commas in a programatic way in your whole table by using a query.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have QGIS installed: you can use Google's (outstanding) geocode functionality easily with the MMQGIS-plugin.

> MMQGIS --> Geocode --> Geocode CSV